# Code in Python that converts .h5 files to .csv

Tags: python, numpy, csv, h5py, sys

I have a .h5 file that I need to convert to .csv and this is what I have done.

```
#coding: utf-8

import numpy as np
import sys
import h5py

file = h5py.File('C:/Users/Sakib/Desktop/VNP46A1.A2020086.h01v01.001.2020087082319.h5','r')
a = list(file.keys())

np.savetxt(sys.stdout, file[a[0:]], '%g', ',')
```

But this generates an error saying 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'

[P.S Also I have not worked with the module sys before. Where will my new csv file be written and with which name?]

Comment: Could you please the content of variable a? Does np.array(file[a[0:]]) create a nd.ndarray?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a small error in the arrangement of the `[]`
. There is no need to create a list.
Also, `sys.stdout` depends on your process "standard output". For an interactive process it will go to the screen. You should create a file and write to it if you want to capture the output. Also, your formatting string (`%g`) needs to match the data in the HDF5 dataset.
Try this:

```
h5f= h5py.File('C:/Users/.....h5','r')
for a in h5f.keys() :
    outf = open('./save_'+a+'.txt','w')
    np.savetxt(outf, file[a][:], '%g', ',')
    outf.close
```